# The keyboard make the UIView slowly when it comes up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

i have an action that allows me to present a ModalViewController and show the UITextField as a first responder, the problem is when this ModalViewController will come up it takes a little time, the cause is the keyboard, and when i grab the code to the viewDidAppear the keyboard take a little time to show up, so how can i do to make the UIViewController comes up quickly?

```
- (IBAction)goToModalViewController
{    
    ModalSearchViewController *msvc = [[ModalSearchViewController alloc] init];
    self.msvc.context = context;
    self.msvc.delegate = self;
    [self.msvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve ];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    [self presentModalViewController:msvc animated:YES];
}
```

The viewWillAppear of the ModalViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:YES];

   [findTextField becomeFirstResponder]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in the `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //[findTextField becomeFirstResponder]; 
    [findTextField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}
```

Comment: You can change the delay depend on how much time you want it to be delayed.